# Deploy 2 containers to Google App Engine Flexible Environment Docker

Tags: google-app-engine, docker

I have a web app running packed in Docker and running in Google App Engine Flexible Environment.

Now I have a worker which also is packed in Docker, this one doesn't have any HTTP listeners.

Is it possible to run both containers in the same Google App Engine app?

Comment: how does the web app communicate with the worker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Google App Engine, currently there is no functionality to compose two or more docker images as a single application, like Docker compose or pods in Kubernetes.

I recommend having a look at [This question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39877521/using-docker-compose-within-google-app-engine).

Basically the only option is multi-process container (using a startup script that starts both of your services).